# Serialized value within a group jms symfony

Tags: symfony, jms-serializer

How can I serialize only a field within a JMS group in symfony?

```
return $this->json($products, Response::HTTP_CREATED, [],
        ['groups' => ['user']]);
```

So I want to be serialized only the user id, not all the user details. 
Any ideas?

EDIT: The method json() belongs to ControllerTrait.

Answer (score 0):

The function `ControllerTrait::json` makes use of `symfony/serializer` and not `jms/serializer`.

JMS Serializer provides means to execute complex serialization/deserialization, whereas Symfony's Serializer only has a subset of those functionalities. You could probably do the get away without JMS's Serializer, just make sure your use:

```
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups
```

instead of:

```
JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups
```

**<kbd>Example</kbd>**

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"simple", "super_simple"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Groups({"full"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Groups({"full"})
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @var Role
     */
    private $role;
}

class Role{
    /**
     * @Groups({"simple"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Groups({"full"})
     */
    private $description;
}
```

And then you could do:

```
$role = new Role(1, "Some role");
$user = new User(1, "foo", "bar", $role);

// Returns ids of both User and Role
$ids = $this->json($user, Response::HTTP_CREATED, [], ['groups' => ['simple']]); 

// Returns id of User entity only (note the different group)
$ids = $this->json($user, Response::HTTP_CREATED, [], ['groups' => ['super_simple']]);
```

Just, make sure that the serialization annotations are enabled (`framework`.`serializer`.`enable_annotations`: `true` in your `config.yml`)

See the docs on this:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Ok, but still, if I will use symfony/serializer how can I extract only the id from user entity, and not the whole user? I tried something like: ['groups' => ['user'].['id']] but obviously its not working..

Comment: Well, I understand your approach but if there are other fields of other classes that are annotated['groups']=> ['consumer'], then how can I display them, and only the id of the user? Thats what I was trying to achieve..

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I think my latest update above could help you go around that. It is super-clean as you are required to introduce additional groups but it does the job...